# Determining the expected value of a point in a random variable in an interval

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

A stick of total length $1$ is split at a randomly selected point $X$, i.e. $X$ is uniformly distributed in the interval $[0, 1]$.

Determine the expected length of the piece that contains the point $1/3$.

I've figured out so far that I need to determine a function $f(x)$ so that the length of the piece will be equal to $L=f(x)$, but I don't know how to work from here?

Comment: If $x<1/3$, then $L(x)=1-x$; if $x>1/3$, then $L(x)=x$. Now integrate $\displaystyle\int_0^1 L(x)\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the length $X$ is $\le 1/3$, the expectation of $X$ is $1/6$, and the expected length of the piece that contains $1/3$ is $5/6$.

Given that $X\gt 1/3$, the expectation of $X$ is $2/3$, so the expected length of the piece that contains $1/3$ is $1/3$.

Thus by the Law of Total Expectation, the expected length of the piece that contains $1/3$ is $(1/3)(5/6)+(2/3)(1/3)$.

*Remark*: The result is $1/2$. I am feeling foolish, since the same argument gives $1/2$ if $1/3$ is replaced by any number $a$. The answer $1/2$ should be "obvious." Maybe tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Because of uniform, $X$ falls to the left of $1/3$ with probability $1/3$. The length of the piece that includes $1/3$ in this case is of length $1 - X$, which can range from $2/3$ to $1$. In expectation this length is $5/6$.

With probability $2/3$, $X$ falls to the right of $1/3$. The length of the piece that includes $1/3$ is now of length $X$, ranging from $1/3$ to $1$, with an expected value of $2/3$.

So the answer you're looking for is $1/3 (5/6) + 2/3 (2/3) = 13/18$.

More generally, the formula is $x \frac{(1 + 1 - x)}{2} + (1-x) \frac{1 + x}{2} = x - x^2 + 1/2$ for any $x \in [0,1]$.